# JMeter Groovy - WebDriver Sampler script failed with Response Code 500

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, jmeter

I am not sure why keep failed with Response Code 500 on my script. Please is my sample code and error messages. Please kindly advise. Many thanks.

**Error Messages:**

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1612415604534,36638,jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler,500,"javax.script.ScriptException: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.146)
```

**Sample Code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get("https://uat-testing.com/");
sleep(10000);
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("xxxx@testing.com");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).clear();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("xxx@xxxx");
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//button/span")).click();
sleep(20000);
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[10]/li/span")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[16]/li/span")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[3]/li/span")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//div[5]/div/div/div")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'dropdown-menu-')]/li")).click();
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("(//button[contains(@type,'button')])")).click();
sleep(30000);
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [ElementNotInteractableException](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotInteractableException.html) means that the element you're trying to work with cannot be used by WebDriver

> Thrown to indicate that although an element is present on the DOM, it is not in a state that can be interacted with.

Most probably it's "covered" by other DOM element so the options are in:

- Use [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) for "waiting" until the element can be accessed (by the way you should also consider replacing your "sleeps" with the explicit waits as it's kind of a performance anti-pattern)
- Instead of trying to work with particular this element you might want to interact with the one which hovers it, to wit change locator to another one
- And finally you can use [JavaScript Executor](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) in order to perform the "click" by means of JavaScript

More information on WebDriver Sampler: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: Thanks so much. Which library need to be import for JMeter WebDriver Java?

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide me some sample code like how to merge my code with the Explicit Wait? I am not sure how to write codes with WDS.browser & WebElement. Many Thanks again